# "Essential C++": Providing Class Instances of the iostream Operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

From *Essential C++:* 4.10 Providing Class Instances of the iostream Operators

> Often, we wish to both read and write objects of a class. For example,
>   to display our trian class object, we want to be able to write

```
cout << train << endl;
```

> To support this, we must provide an overloaded instance of the output
>   operator:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const Triangular &rhs)
{
    os << "(" << rhs.beg_pos() << "," << rhs.length() << ")";
    rhs.display(rhs.length(), rhs.beg_pos(), os);
    return os;
}
```

> We return the same ostream object passed into the function. This
>   allows multiple outptu operators to be concatenated. Both objects are
>   passed by reference. **The ostream operand is not declared as const
>   because each output operation modifies the internal state of the
>   ostream object.**

I'm kind of confused why the ostream operand cannot be declared as const.
If the output operator is declared as the following:

```
const ostream& operator<< (const ostream &os, const Triangular &rhs)
```

Is there any problem with the above declaration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if the `ostream` argument (or conversely `istream`) was a constant reference, then the operator would not be able to modify the stream object. Insertion/extraction to the streams *modify* the stream state, so the existing `operator<<` are non-const operations. That in turn means that while you can *declare* and even *define*:

```
std::ostream const & operator<<( std::ostream const & s, Type const & t );
```

The problem is that the definition would not be able to actually *write* anything at all into the stream:

```
std::ostream const & operator<<( std::ostream const & s, Type const & t ) {
   s << "Hi";     // Error: operator<<( std::ostream&, const char*) requires a
                  //        non-const `std::ostream&`
   return s;      // This is fine
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When outputting the variable `rhs`, some data members inside `ostream& os` such as output buffer or position of file write if `os` is a `ofstream` must be modified.

Declaring `os` as `const` forbids such a modification.

And, as shown [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/), if `os` is declared as `const`, then you cannot use it to output primitive data types since none of `ostream::operator<<()` is declared as constant member function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ostream argument os is modified by calling <<.